# From where to start webservices in android?

Tags: php, android, web-services

Some people vote down after seeing these kinds of question. So if anyone votedown please tell the reason so that I may improve.

I am learning Android and I started studying webservices.

I used this php code

```
<?php 
echo "hello abhi how are you";
?>
```

and this code in the Activity class of android application

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        BufferedReader in = null;
        TextView tv1;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        HttpPost httppost;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/devilabhi/a.php");
                new getresult().execute();


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
        }

        public class getresult extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


                String result = null;
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try {
                                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
                        }
                        return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPostExecute(result1);
                        tv1.setText(result);
                        Log.i("My Response :: ", result);
                }

        }

}
```

and I got output as

[image]

Now next step I want to learn is how to save name and email or anything else in database on server and how to retrieve that or I must study something else first so that I may understand this thing easily
I searched regarding this and I got the [link](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) but there is no php code so I may not try this code

Is there any website, link or any example for us beginners to study and learn webservices.

Your suggestions and answers and very valuable for me and beginners like me. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The reason these get frequently downvoted is that they frequently get asked without showing the asker has put any effort into researching how to do things.  You've at least shown some, so I'll give you some next steps.

1)Sending parameters.  You're going to need to choose whether to use an HTTP GET or HTTP POST request.  In a GET, the parameters are embedded in the url-  http://example.com?param1=val1&param2=val2 for example.  In a POST, they're embedded in the request.  There's reasons to use each type, but you can google that later.

2)On the PHP side, you can read the values using $_GET["param1"] or $_POST["param1"] depending on the way you sent them.

3)You then have to connect to the database and write SQL queries to INSERT the data.  You're best off googling for a tutorial on using your specific db and PHP here.

Comment: thanks for you valuable answer I am learning android. I firstly want to make my android concepts clear than I'll move to php and all. Now i want to learn how to connect to webservices and send and retrieve data from webservices